# App crashes when trying to open a fragment with listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My app crashes when I try to open a fragment consisting of a listview.

Scenario:

1. Opens fragmentA for the first time, listview does not show.
2. Clicks the button (that goes to fragmentB) on fragmentA.
3. Clicks back button while on fragmentB, listview on fragmentA shows.
4. Exits app, tries to open fragmentA again, app crashes.

My Fragment class:

```
public class FamilyTreeFragment extends Fragment {

// Declare Variables
ListView listview;
List<ParseObject> ob;
ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
FamilyTreeListViewAdapter adapter;
private List<FamilyTree> familytreelist = null;
View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

    new RemoteDataTask().execute();
    // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
    listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
    // adapter = new FamilyTreeListViewAdapter(getActivity(), familytreelist);
    // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    // listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    // Close the progressdialog
    mProgressDialog.dismiss();

    // btn_add
    Button btn_add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
    btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Toast.makeText(SuggestionsFragment.this.getActivity(),
            // "You have selected Parks.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FamilyTreeFragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

// RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Create the array
        familytreelist = new ArrayList<FamilyTree>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("FamilyTree");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject familytree : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) familytree.get("image");

                FamilyTree tree = new FamilyTree();
                tree.setName((String) familytree.get("name"));
                tree.setRelation((String) familytree.get("relation"));
                tree.setImage(image.getUrl());
                familytreelist.add(tree);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FamilyTreeListViewAdapter(getActivity(), familytreelist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        // mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/familytreecontainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.parcel.FamilyTreeFragment$PlaceholderFragment" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="407dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.86" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_add"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add" />
```

Logcat:

```
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072): Process: com.example.parcel, PID: 22072
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at  com.example.parcel.FamilyTreeFragment$RemoteDataTask.onPostExecute(FamilyTreeFragment.java:111)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at com.example.parcel.FamilyTreeFragment$RemoteDataTask.onPostExecute(FamilyTreeFragment.java:1)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5867)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
11-06 17:01:06.500: E/AndroidRuntime(22072):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

**Replace With**

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

**Error reason :**

You have decalre rootView at class level but not initialize in on onCreateView(),you taken View rootView as local variable in onCreateView() so onPostExecute() rootView will be point to class level variable which is still not initialize.

**Well Formatted code :**

```
public class FamilyTreeFragment extends Fragment {

    // Declare Variables
    private ListView listview;
    private Button btn_add;
    private FamilyTreeListViewAdapter adapter;
    private List<FamilyTree> familytreelist;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

        listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        btn_add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        btn_add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Toast.makeText(SuggestionsFragment.this.getActivity(),
                // "You have selected Parks.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FamilyTreeFragment2()).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        new RemoteDataTask().execute();
        return rootView;
    }

    // RemoteDataTask AsyncTask
    private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<FamilyTree>> {
        private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();

        }

        protected List<FamilyTree> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            // Create the array
            List<FamilyTree> list = new ArrayList<FamilyTree>();
            try {
                // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("FamilyTree");
                // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
                // by ascending
                query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
                List<ParseObject> ob = query.find();
                for (ParseObject familytree : ob) {
                    // Locate images in flag column
                    ParseFile image = (ParseFile) familytree.get("image");

                    FamilyTree tree = new FamilyTree();
                    tree.setName((String) familytree.get("name"));
                    tree.setRelation((String) familytree.get("relation"));
                    tree.setImage(image.getUrl());
                    list.add(tree);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return list;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<FamilyTree> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(mProgressDialog!=null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()){
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            if(familytreelist==null){
                familytreelist = new ArrayList<FamilyTree>();
            }

            familytreelist.addAll(result);

            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new FamilyTreeListViewAdapter(getActivity(), familytreelist);
            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi. I have replaced
    
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

with

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_familytree, container, false);

and removed the declared listview at onPostExecute() and it works! Thank you so much!

Comment: if you are remove listview initialization from onPostExecute() then move listview initialization line before this new RemoteDataTask().execute(); line in onCreateView().

Comment: Okay. I have made the changes. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh I understand now. The progress dialog is now working as it should. Thank you so much for your help!